# Can I change my trade ports?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

As Germany, I'm importing lots of oil from South America. However, it's all being delivered to a port in (occupied) Holland, which takes it straight through the English Channel, and most of it gets sunk.

Is there a way to have them deliver it to a different port? The south coast of France (also occupied) is much better defended, navy-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are able to change trade ports manually. See [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/hoi4/comments/4sb3ne/annoying_trade_routes/d584kvz):

> Trade routes are automated.

I have found nothing to indicate that you are able to change trade ports, so it looks like you're stuck with whatever it chooses for you initially.

Answer (score 3):

With the Man the Guns DLC it is now (2019) possible to control the routes used for trade convoys. You can indicate that a sea zone is avoided if possible or even forbidden in all cases.

I have used this feature to route convoys out of air range and away from contested sea zones. That has indirectly changed the *destination* port for convoys. But I can't confirm that it will change the departure *port*.